# How will I surely know whether the note I sang was right when compared to its previous note and if I was singing the proper scale?

Tags: theory

In a C Major scale (C,D,E,F,G,B,A) , If I were to play it over a piano, will it be right if I play C1,D5,E1,F1,G1,A1,B1 - simply put for a scale can I play keys as per names but with different pitches. If not why? The reason why I asked this question is if I were to detect my tone using an application and then improve my vocals and tune with an instrument, how will I surely know whether the note I sang was right when compared to its previous note and if I was singing proper scale?

Comment: Major scale usually goes C,D,E,F,G,*A*, *B*.

Comment: Are you asking how to distinguish two of the same note in different octaves?  Any half-decent app or tuner can do this.  Are you asking how to hear it?  What trouble are you having?

Comment: Hi Matthew Read , yes I was referring same note in different octaves. My point was , how do I identify the harmonious sounds which I can sing or play and would it be ok if I substitute the note from a different octave in place of another....If I do that would I lose the harmony in music. Also If I substitute same notes from different octaves can we still refer to it as a scale.

Comment: A scale consists of an ascending/descending group of notes, ordered by pitch, (not just name) so no, it can't be a scale.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chances are, unless you're a trained singer, if you did that, you'd probably sing an ordinary scale. If indeed, you could play exactly what you wrote!

Jumping up a whole octave or more is not what most songs do, so it would feel alien to you. Your voice would probably compensate by doing what I described at the start.

So, how would you know? By recording the event and playing it back and listening. Most likely with disbelief!

Comment: Bit of a revelation! Voted accepted answer by OP, but downvoted by ? because of what?? I'm just intrigued - again! Love to know what mileage anyone gets...